# java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available at org.easymock.getControlForLastCall (EasyMock.java:559)

Tags: unit-testing, junit, powermock, easymock

I am trying to mock a static non final method using PowerMock. My test class annotations look like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassicRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TestClazz.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"filePath"})
```

My test looks something like this:

```
// A few mocks being defined here, for instance
// EasyMock.expect(someObject.getFirstName("First Second")).andReturn("First");

PowerMock.mockStatic(TestClazz.class);
EasyMock.expect(TestClazz.staticMethod(EasyMock.anyString())).andReturn("returnString");
PowerMock.replayAll();

object.methodCall();

PowerMock.verifyAll();
```

I am getting an error that says:

```
no last call on a mock available

java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available
at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControlForLastCall(EasyMock.java:559)
at org.easymock.EasyMock.expect(EasyMock.java:537)
```

I need the runner to be `SpringJUnit4ClassicRunner` as I need to load the `ApplicationContext` first and then mock the required classes.

I am not sure what I am missing here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Based on @Henri's suggestion I tried using the `@PowerMockRunnerDelegate`. This is the stackTrace I encounter:
`InitializationError`

```
Failed to transform class with name MyTest. Reason: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name MyTest. Reason: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:266)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:180)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:145)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:40)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:244)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:61)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
at javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile2(CtClassType.java:207)
at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:110)
at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:96)
at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(TypeChecker.java:704)
at javassist.expr.NewExpr$ProceedForNew.setReturnType(NewExpr.java:240)
at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:146)
at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:45)
at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atVariableAssign(TypeChecker.java:248)
at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atAssignExpr(TypeChecker.java:217)
at javassist.compiler.ast.AssignExpr.accept(AssignExpr.java:38)
at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:235)
at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:323)
at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:344)
at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atIfStmnt(CodeGen.java:398)
at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:348)
at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:558)
at javassist.expr.NewExpr.replace(NewExpr.java:204)
at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer$PowerMockExpressionEditor.edit(MainMockTransformer.java:418)
at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.loopBody(ExprEditor.java:198)
at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:90)
at javassist.CtClassType.instrument(CtClassType.java:1224)
at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.transform(MainMockTransformer.java:74)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:251)
```

My config has EasyMock-3.x, PowerMockEasyMock-1.6.x and PowerMockAgentJUnit4-1.6.x.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you still need the `PowerMockRunner`. The trick is to use `PowerMockRunnerDelegate`, like this

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TestClazz.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        PowerMock.mockStatic(TestClazz.class);
        EasyMock.expect(TestClazz.staticMethod(EasyMock.anyString())).andReturn("returnString");
        PowerMock.replayAll();

        assertEquals("returnString", TestClazz.staticMethod("aaa"));

        PowerMock.verifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried doing that but I encounter an error that says: `Failed to transform class with name {MyTest path}. Reason: java.io.IOException: Invalid constant type: 18. `. I will update the full stackTrace in the question.

Comment: Something is mismatching between your PowerMock, Java and Javassist versions I would say.